# Variable to hold a two dimensional array of objects

Tags: c++

I have created a two dimensional array of myOwnClass in ClassA

```
class classA
{
  public:
    myOwnClass* myArray[2][16];  
}
```

How can I create a variable in another class(ClassB) that can point to this array.

If I have a one dimensional array defined 
 `myOwnClass* myArray[16]` 
I can just define a variable like this to hold the array `myOwnClass** myArrayPointer`, so everything work fine with a one dimensional array, but I can not get it to work with a two dimensional array. I tried to define the variable as `myOwnClass*** myArrayPointer`, but that does obviously not work.

Comment: As it stands, that `myArray` looks like a three dimensional array (or a pointer to a 2d array at least). Is that star a typo? Also, beware, you're straying into [3 Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) territory. Especially if you're in C++ I'd recommend `std::vector`'s

Comment: @scohe001 Nope, it is a 2D array of pointers.

Comment: @juanchopanza +1, you're right, that's a bad parse on my part. Still holds that it could be a three dimensional array though.

Comment: *Variable to hold a two dimensional array of objects*  -- Before even going forward, do *you* know what you have a two-dimensional array of?  It certainly isn't objects.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using "raw" C-style arrays instead of a C++-style [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: So you want something line `struct classB { myOwnClass* (*pClassArray)[2][16]; };` and `b.pClassArray = &a.myArray;`?

Comment: That is an *array of pointers*. Can you not use `std::array` for some reason?

Comment: To add up on _@scohe001's_ and @Ben's comment, you can also use `std::array<std::array<myOwnClass*>16>,2>` if your indices are fixed.at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I can not get it to work with a two dimensional array. I tried to define the variable as myOwnClass*** myArrayPointer, but that does obviously not work.

Array and pointer are different things, only at the outer-most level, an array will decay to a pointer. So in your case, that variable's second level type is not a pointer, it's an array of 16 elements.

Use this:

```
myOwnClass* (*my_another_var)[16] = some_instance.myArray;
```

Comment: @Thomas _"Perfect, this works!"_ Not very far with serious production ready c++ code, believe me!

Comment: @TheDude Are you randomly downvoting others' answer ?

Comment: @liliscent Certainly not _"randomly"_. There's no worse advise you could have given. (myriads of dupes aside)

Comment: @TheDude SO is for **answering question**, *not* **doing advise**. OP has problems about complicated pointer declaration, I answered the question with reasonable explanation, which **solved** the question OP has posed. If your criterion makes your downvote such answer, I think it's even worse than **random**.

Comment: @liliscent I'd not consider that a _canonical_, and _idiomatic_ solution for a c++ language problem though. There need to be tough requirements to reason the use of raw c-style arrays or raw pointers nowadays.

Comment: @TheDude I totally agree with what you said, that's also what C++ programmer will do in practice. But this is **not** a reasonable criterion to judge a question or an answer. You can't **teach** OP how to write code, **they will learn by themselves in practice**. For the moment they are asking question, they want to get a concrete answer to solve their **specific** problem. They don't want an answer telling them to totally rewrite their code. We don't use such pointers, but we all know how to write those complicated pointers. This answer is valuable for those who don't know.

Comment: @TheDude Please remove this downvote if you think what I said makes sense.

Comment: @liliscent As mentioned _**tough requirements and reasons**_ needed. Just for a _YAIT's_ or _YAIP's_ pleasure isn't enough to _chuck_ Norris :-P ...

Comment: @liliscent Pro tip: You could profit a lot of just stealing and incorporating [@Nicos' unexplained (!sic) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695564/9212993).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <array>

class ClassA
{
public:
    // Give it a friendly name.
    using MyArray_t = std::array<std::array<myOwnClass, 16>, 2>;

    // Now you can use that name as if it were a type.
    MyArray_t myArray;
};

class ClassB
{
    ClassA::MyArray_t* arrayPtr = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: Even though I don't like that _code only answer_ style. I give the upvote here, because it exactly reflects what I've [_been arguing about_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695210/variable-to-hold-a-two-dimensional-array-of-objects/48695243?noredirect=1#comment84390322_48695243).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
struct classB
{
    myOwnClass* (*pClassArray)[2][16];  
};
```

Initialize it like this:

```
classA a;    // ..init a.myArray;
classB b;
b.pClassArray = &a.myArray;
```

And use it:

```
cout << (*b.pClassArray)[i][j] << " ";
```

<kbd>[BAD Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8bdc7c664f14dc0)</kbd>